# How to programmatically disable/enable delete button in CQ5

Tags: aem

I want to customize the delete button's functionality in CQ5. Basically, for some conditions I want this delete button is disabled in the siteAdmin. Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to overlay the siteadmin configuration located at /libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin.  Copy this to /apps/wcm/core/content/siteadmin and then add a custom javascript function to the conditions field of the delete button.

conditions="[CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.hasAnySelection,CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.notLocked,CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.canDeleteReplicatedPage,**CustomJSFunc**]"

*NOTE:  I found a bug in CQ where your siteadmin overlay may not be used in certain cases.  To make sure it is always used overlay /libs/cq/ui/components/widget/html.jsp, make a copy at /apps/cq/ui/components/widget/html.jsp.  Then modify the CQ.Util.build call at the very end to include the .overlay selector.

CQ.Util.build("<%= slingRequest.getContextPath() %><%= currentNode.getPath() %>**.overlay**.infinity.json", null, null, debug, extensionString);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I have implemented it and am able to call the js function. But now the requirement is that the delete button should be disable if some property is true in the jcr:content node. So, is it possible to call any property of the jcr:content node from the js function.

Comment: It will be a little difficult to determine how to do it without seeing your code, but here goes.  Try something like 

var selectedPage = this.getSelectedPages()[0];
var path = selectedPage.id;
var primaryType = CQ.HTTP.eval(CQ.HTTP.get(path + '/_jcr_content.json'))['jcr:primaryType'];